# How to parse HTML using ElementTree to find a particular RegEx?

Tags: python, regex, data-structures, elementtree

Using Python 2.7.6 Along with ElementTree to load / parse an HTML file from the filesystem and then iterate through the file to store a particular RegEx into a data structure.

So, inside my project's folder, I have an HTML file entitled person.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Name: $name</li>
            <li>Age: $age</li>
        </ul>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Here's my Python script (main.py) so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import web
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

tree = ET.parse(person.html)
```

Question (s):

1. How do I parse using a RegEx or ElementTree values that begin with `$` (such as `$name` and `$age`)?
2. How do I store these values into a data structure that I could iterate through in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Kevin & 7stud, I got it working like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import re

with open("person.html", "r") as html_file:
    data=html_file.read()   
list_of_strings = re.findall(r'\$[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*', data)
print list_of_strings
```

Outputs:

```
[$name, $age]
```

Comment: never use regular expressions to parse HTML.

Answer (score 6):

`lxml` is used to search html ***by tags***.  For example, if you want to locate all the `<li>` tags, and get their text:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

tree = et.parse('data.html')
html_tag = tree.getroot()

for li in html_tag.iter('li'):
    text = li.text
    print(text)

--output:--
Name: $name
Age: $age
```

If your target text can be in any tag, then you could do this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import re

tree = et.parse('data.html')
html_tag = tree.getroot()

pattern = r"""
    \$
    .*?
    \b
"""

for tag in html_tag.iter('*'):  # '*' => all tags
    text = tag.text.strip()

    if text: 
        match_list = re.findall(pattern, text, flags=re.X)
        print (match_list)

--output:--
['$name']
['$age']
```

> How do I store these values into a data structure that I could iterate
>   through in the future?

You can use the `shelve` module:

```
$ cat data.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Name: $name</li>
            <li>Age: $age</li>
            <li>Dogs: $dog1, $dog2</li>     
        </ul>
    </body> 
</html>
```

---

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import re
import shelve
import collections as coll

tree = et.parse('data.html')
html_tag = tree.getroot()

pattern = r"""
    \$    #Match a literal $ sign...
    .+?   #followed by any character, 1 or more times, non-greedy
    \b    #followed by the (first) word boundary
"""

results = coll.defaultdict(list)

for tag in html_tag.iter('*'):
    text = tag.text.strip()

    if text: 
        match_list = re.findall(pattern, text, flags=re.X)
        if match_list:
            results['data.html'].extend(match_list)


print(results)

with shelve.open('mydb.db') as db:
    db['html vars'] = results

with shelve.open('mydb.db') as db:
    for key, val in db['html vars'].items():
        print("{}: {}".format(key, val))

--output:--
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'data.html': ['$name', '$age', '$dog1', '$dog2']})

data.html: ['$name', '$age', '$dog1', '$dog2']
```

If your ultimate goal is to replace those variables in the html, your format fits python's `template` format:

```
import string

with open('data.html') as f:
    template = string.Template(f.read())


values = {
    'name': 'socal_javaguy',
    'age': 25,
    'dog1': 'Rover',
    'dog2': 'Jane',
}

results = template.substitute(values)
print(results)

--output:--
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Name: socal_javaguy</li>
            <li>Age: 25</li>
            <li>Dogs: Rover, Jane</li>     
        </ul>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about use RegEx like this:

```
>>> html = """
... <!DOCTYPE html>
... <html>
...     <body>
...         <ul>
...             <li>Name: $name</li>
...             <li>Age: $age</li>
...         </ul>
...     </body> 
... </html>
... """
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\$\w*', html)
['$name', '$age']
>>>
```

[`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) return a list so you can use them like this:

```
>>> l = re.findall(r'\$\w*', html)
>>> l
['$name', '$age']
>>> l[0]
'$name'
>>> l[1]
'$age'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin! However, this is treating the html as a String... Is there a way  (such as a library) to load it as a HTML file and then turn into a String and then use your regex code?

Comment: @socal_javaguy: Well, every file loaded in Python is string hum? So isn't `person.html` string?